# How do I calculate PSD, Median Frequency and Mean Frequency in python?

Tags: python, signal-processing, fft, feature-extraction, frequency-analysis

I am trying to extract frequency features from EMG Data on python with a sliding window. I do not have too much knowledge on frequency analysis, so I apologize in advance if I've got some wrong concepts.

I am trying to follow the definitions from this website:

[MDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udOFg.png)

[more information](https://www.intechopen.com/books/computational-intelligence-in-electromyography-analysis-a-perspective-on-current-applications-and-future-challenges/the-usefulness-of-mean-and-median-frequencies-in-electromyography-analysis)

My questions are whether I am performing the calculations right, and if not how can I proceed to calculate them?

```
Windows_Size = 0.125 
Overlap = 0.5 
Bins = 256 

START, END = df_filtered['Time'].min(), df_filtered['Time'].max()
Fs = 2000 #EMG Sampling Frequency
P = 1.0 / Fs

Windows = np.arange(START + Windows_Size, END, Windows_Size * (1 - Overlap))
FREQ = []

for w in WINDOWS:
  win_start, win_end = w - Windows_Size, w

  for var in ['Biceps_Femoris_Sq_Correct']:
    value = df_filtered.loc[(win_start <= df_filtered['Time']) & (df_filtered['Time'] < win_end), var].values

    fft = np.fft.fft(value * np.hamming(value.shape[0]), n=Bins)[1:Bins//2]
    freq = np.fft.fftfreq(Bins, P)[1:Bins//2]
    amp = np.abs(fft)

    energy = amp ** 2 # Is this the right way to calculate power spectrum? 

    median_freq = energy/2 
    #mean_freq = EMG power spectrum is divided into two regions with equal 
    #amplitude... is this right?

    mean_freq = np.sum(energy * freq) / np.sum(energy)
```

Average frequency which is calculated as the sum of product of the EMG power 
spectrum, and the frequency divided by the total sum of the power spectrum. Is this the right way to calculate mean frequency?

Comment: mean_freq seems right, but the mdf is wrong. MDF should be the frequency that split energy into two identical part (in surface). MDF should use a cumsum on the energy and you should find where the cumsum is at max(cumsum/2)

Answer (score 0):

the MDF should be something like

```
energy_cumsum = np.cumsum(energy)
MDF = freq[np.where(energy_cumsum>np.max(energy_cumsum)/2)[0][0]]
```